# Why does a private attribute of python class allow me to assign a value?

Tags: python

I have a class with private attribute

```
class DoGood():
     __prv = "i m private"
     def __init__(self):
         self.default_string = self.__prv

     def say_it_aloud(self):
         print self.default_string
```

I m trying to access the private attribute from python-cli

```
>>> from sample import DoGood
>>> obj = DoGood()
>>> obj.__prv
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: DoGood instance has no attribute '__pro'
```

Since its private i m not able to access it **But** when i try to assign a value i m able to do it

```
>>> obj.__prv = "changed in subclass"
>>> obj.say_it_aloud()
i m private
```

However the value inside the class object has not changed. But why i m able to assign it do it serve any purpose

Comment: `obj.__pro` is a typo.

Comment: You created a new attribute, just like if you had done `obj.someOtherAttribute = "blah"`.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of that, although it's related.  This question is substantially more specific.

Comment: Thanks BrenBarn ppl read the question and answer it, please do not skim and answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a new attribute to the instance you have created for that class. It is not changing the __prv attribute's value.

```
print DoGood._DoGood__prv # access a private attribute.
```

will still output "i am private"

Comment: not because it is private though, it's because it is a class attribute.

Comment: Yes @perreal. Even though it was an instance variable, the private attribute will be mapped as _ClassName__attrname, so if we reassign the attribute, it wont change the actual attribute.